# recursive user defined function in makefile runs out of stack memory

Tags: recursion, makefile, out-of-memory, wildcard

I have a function that returns all the files in a directory.

```
# Returns all files in folder recursively that match pattern 
# 
# $(call rwildcard, folder,pattern)
rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))
```

Argument 1, i.e. folder, is the path of the folder where to search for files recursively and it's user provided

If this argument is "/" this would run out of memory and crash with an exception.

Is there a way to prevent this? besides filtering  "/" as an argument.

Note: i'm using cygwin

Comment: I'm going to guess the answer is "no". If make cannot allocate enough memory to contain the list of values asked for things are going to go badly. I suppose you might be able to add logic in there to check the length of the returned value during the recursion and manually error/etc. if the list starts getting too long but I'm not sure how easy that would actually be to do.

Comment: Yes. That's what I kind of had in mind though not sure how to to this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you aren't making any progress in the inner rwildcard.  If it matches "." every time, are you stuck in a loop?

Can you use another tool to get a list of files?

```
r := $(shell find $(dir) -type f -name \*$(likethis)\*)
```

Comment: Using an external tool like `find` is a good idea, but it's not the case that the recursion is infinite; a wildcard like `*` doesn't match hidden files so `/*` will never match `/.` (or `/..`)

Comment: The function works correctly with folders that have a relatively small depth and number of dirs.
The problem occurs when the entire root is parsed. 
I know 'find' would work well here but my intent is not to use any external tools